# Using a href to navigate from one cshtml view to another

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

So this might sound silly but I'm really stuck. I have an HTML a tag in my cshtml layout view that is supposed to redirect to another cshtml view page. Despite trying different ways to generate the correct path, clicking on the link still returns 404 not found. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Please provide some code :)

Answer (score 1):

I realized I need to have a method in the controller for every view. Didn't know that before. It's working fine now. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `asp-page` tag helper to route to another page.

Below is an example:

```
<td><a class="text-info" asp-page="NameOfPageYouWantRoutedTo" asp-route-id="@Model.ID">@Model.ID</a></td>
```

Depending on where your new cshtml page is you may have change the filepath, but this should get you close. `The asp-route-id` tag helper would link whatever value of the link to the new page. Delete that tag helper if not needed.

This is a pretty good [link](https://exceptionnotfound.net/anchor-tag-helpers-route-data-and-query-strings-in-asp-net-core-3-0/) on tag helpers that would be useful for what you're trying to accomplish.